# Resizing makes sprite disappear love2d

Tags: lua, game-development, love2d

So, I was working on my love2d project when I had this gun sprite, it was way too big so I though since love2d's love.graphics.draw() function had sx and sy as arguments I could just put it there. But when I did that the sprite disappeared.
Here's my love.draw() function:

```
function love.draw()
    if playerRotation == 0 then
        love.graphics.draw(player.sprite, playerCollider:getX() - player.width + player.width / 3, playerCollider:getY() - player.height * 2 + player.height / 2)
    elseif playerRotation == 1 then
        love.graphics.draw(player.spriteLeft, playerCollider:getX() - player.width + player.width / 3, playerCollider:getY() - player.height * 2 + player.height / 2)
    end
    love.graphics.draw(ground.sprite, ground.x, ground.y, 0, love.graphics.getWidth(), love.graphics.getHeight())
    love.graphics.draw(gun.sprite, playerCollider:getX(), playerCollider:getY(), 0, gun.width, gun.height)
end
```

My player "class":

```
local class = require('libraries/middleclass')

local Player = class('Player')

function Player:init()
    self.x = 350
    self.y = 100
    self.width = 80
    self.height = 80
    self.sprite = love.graphics.newImage('sprites/player.png')
    self.spriteLeft = love.graphics.newImage('sprites/player-left.png')
    self.jumps = 0
    self.maxJumps = 1
end

return Player
```

Gun "class":

```
local class = require('libraries/middleclass')
local Player = require('player')
local Gun = Player:subclass('gun')

Gun:init()
Gun.sprite = love.graphics.newImage('sprites/gun.png')

return Gun
```

I tried to change the width to a single number, but that didn't work. It just kept disappearing for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sx` and `sy` arguments are scaling factors, `1.0` means that the sprite will be drawn with the original size in selected axis. By default `sx = 1` and `sy = sx`. See [`love.graphics.draw`](https://love2d.org/wiki/love.graphics.draw) for reference.

The way that you define `Gun` it will have its `width` and `height` set to `80` due to `Gun:init()` call that calls `Player.init(Gun)`. Middleclass usage aside, this is a ridiculously big factor and could be that a transparent section of gun is drawn to the screen creating the illusion of not drawing anything.

You want to make the gun smaller - set the factors to something between `0` and `1`.

Regarding the middleclass, if you rename your `init` member functions to `initialize` then middleclass will call them on instance construction. Also, define initializer for `Gun` instead of operating on the class itself:

```lua
local Player = class('Player')

function Player:initialize()
  self.sprite = 'sprites/player.png'  -- just to illustrate; use newImage
end

local Gun = Player:subclass('Gun')

function Gun:initialize()
  Player.initialize(self)
  self.sprite = 'sprites/gun.png'
end

player = Player()
gun = Gun()
print(player.sprite)  --> sprites/player.png
print(gun.sprite)     --> sprites/gun.png
```

I'd encourage you to think over Gun --> Player inheritance.

Comment: Omg this is so embarrassing. Your answer is right, the gun might've been too big. But in main.lua I forgot to initialize gun.